# how to stop user putting HTML code in text inputs

Tags: php, html

iv been building a website and while testing I noticed that if I put `<em>bob</em>`

or something similar in my text fields on my register/udate pages they are stored on the database as entered  `'<em>bob</em>'` but when called back on to the website they display in italics

is there a way to block html code from my text inputs?
or dose it only read as html when being echoed back on the page from the database?
mostly just curious to know what's happening here?
the name displaying in italics isn't a major issue but seems like something the user shouldn't be able to control?

p.s. i can provide code if needed but didn't think it would be much help in this question?

Comment: You can check HTML Purifier.

Comment: The point is: You can't stop them! They will try anyway and all you can do is protect your code. You may use javascript, for instance, to avoid characters as ">" and "<". But this is not a good solution, since these symbols may appear in a valid input. Another solution, at server side, is to use strip_tags function to remove this kind of code. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Instead of stopping user from putting HTML code simply handle those at your code part simply using [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or if you want to get rid of tags then simply use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `strip_tags` to remove all HTML tags from a string: http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text); // Output: Test paragraph. Other text
echo "\n";

// Allows <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>'); // Output: <p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also just use `htmlspecialchars()` to output exactly what they typed on the page — as-is.

So if they enter `<i>bob</i>` then what will show up on the page is literally `<i>bob</i>` — that way you're "allowing" all the input in the world, but none of it is ever rendered.

If you want to just get rid of the tags, `strip_tags()` is the better option, so `<i>bob</i>` would show up as `bob`. This works if you're sure there's no legitimate scenario where someone would want to enter an HTML tag. (For example, Stack Overflow obviously can't just strip the tags out of stuff we type, since a lot of questions involve typing HTML tags.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use builtin PHP function [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). It will remove all HTML tags from a string and return the result.

Something like that:

```
$cleaned_string = strip_tags($_GET['field']);
```